# How to open all image with OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

I try to open image with OpenCVSharp, but it does not open properly. Size of output image is too big.

[Image I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6xA.jpg)

[Code below gives this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLndY.jpg)

```
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace east
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var src = Cv2.ImRead(@"path to image", ImreadModes.Grayscale))
            {
                using (new Window("dst image", src, WindowFlags.AutoSize))
                {
                    Cv2.WaitKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to resize the window. Use `Resize()`.

```
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace east
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var src = Cv2.ImRead(@"C:\Users\Denis\Downloads\len.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale))
            {
                Mat dst = new Mat();
                Size size = new Size(512, 380);
                Cv2.Resize(src, dst, size);

                using (new Window("dst image", dst, WindowFlags.AutoSize))
                {
                    Cv2.WaitKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```